# Ruby Hash populated from Array.product yields unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby, hash

I wanted to pre-populate a Hash, given an array of keys and a default value (an empty array). I attempted to do this using the `#product` method of `Array`.

```
> hash = Hash[[:foo, :bar].product([[]])]   # => {:foo=>[], :bar=>[]}
> hash[:foo].push(:baz)                     # => {:foo=>[:baz], :bar=>[:baz]}
```

I don't understand why the value is being applied to all keys in the hash. If instead, I use the returned value of `product` and populate the hash directly from that, I get expected behavior.

```
> [:foo, :bar].product([[]])              # => [[:foo, []], [:bar, []]]
> hash = Hash[[[:foo, []], [:bar, []]]]   # => {:foo=>[], :bar=>[]}
> hash[:foo].push(:baz)                   # => {:foo=>[:baz], :bar=>[]}
```

I am using ruby 2.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the arrays that you pass to your hash initializer are the same object, so if you modify said object, the changes will be present everywhere it is used:

```
> hash = Hash[[:foo, :bar].product([[]])]
 # => {:foo=>[], :bar=>[]} 
> hash[:foo].object_id
 # => 47106586247680 
> hash[:bar].object_id
 # => 47106586247680
```

If you copy-paste the output of your `product`, you're using 2 different arrays as they get instantiated separately.